# can't locate element behind <span> on a website using xpath or css selector

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

On this [webpage](https://tengrinews.kz/kazakhstan_news/strogiy-karantin-vvodyat-v-mangistauskoy-oblasti-408772/) I inspected number of comments - 42, i need to catch it.
It's located in this span element

```
<span><i class="tn-icon-comment-dark">
</i>42</span>
```

Hovering over the actual number 42 inside the inspector menu the  shows it has #text attribute on the actual webpage.

i tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
news_url = 'https://tengrinews.kz/kazakhstan_news/strogiy-karantin-vvodyat-v-mangistauskoy-oblasti-408772/'

driver.get(news_url)
u =driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/main/section/div/div[4]/div[1]').get_attribute('#text')
print(u)
print(u.text)
print(u.text())
print(u.get_attribute('#text'))

driver.quit()
```

the output:

```
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\curent_time_playing.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(u.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two approach for this problem,

1. Get the `text` of the element & split it and get the number based on the position. By default, it returns `type str` (need to type cast, if you want to use it as integer)

   ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    news_url = 'https://tengrinews.kz/kazakhstan_news/strogiy-karantin-vvodyat-v-mangistauskoy-oblasti-408772/'
    driver.get(news_url)

    u=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/main/section/div/div[4]/div[1]').text
    print(u.split()[0])
   ```
2. You can directly get the `xpath` of that `<span>` tag & get the text. Since the content is not in English, I'm not able to figure out which comment are you exactly looking for.

Comment: thank u, but how would i know i need split() and 0? when i printed 'u' it was None!

Comment: Earlier, it didn't return anything when you used `get_attribute('#text')`, that's why you got `None`. But if you use `text` method, it returns a string of 2 words `(41 some_text)`. When you split the string & get the `index 0`, it's the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the relative XPath you can use :

```
(//div[@class="tn-comment-accordion-title"]//span)[1]
```

Output :

```
<span>
<i class="tn-icon-comment-dark"/>
31
</span>
```

Use `.text` to extract the number of comments.